# RestEasy endpoint throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.constructType

Tags: spring, rest, jackson, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a PUT endpoint which accepts a path param and a request body. Here's a snipped from the controller method. @PathParam seems to be working fine as expected. But getting an exception when request body is provided.

```
@PUT
@Path("/post/{addressId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testPost(@PathParam("addressId") Long addressId,Test test) {

    LOG.info(" inside testPost ");

    Response r = null;
    TestResponse testResponse = new TestResponse();
    try {

        testResponse.setMessage("Successful....");
        testResponse.setTest(test);

        r = Response.ok(testResponse).build();

    } catch (Exception e){
        LOG.error(e);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Here's the POJO class

```
public class Test {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String age;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Request body doesn't seems to be picking up by the endpoint. As I'm getting bellow error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.constructType(Ljava&#47;lang&#47;reflect&#47;Type;)Lorg&#47;codehaus&#47;jackson&#47;type&#47;JavaType;
    org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:61)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:168)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:114)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:255)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:220)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:209)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:496)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

These are some dependencies I have added which I believe would be useful for this.

```
httpclient-4.0.3.jar
httpcore-4.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.3.jar
jackson-xc-1.6.3.jar
jaxrs-api-3.0.12.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.1.0.Final.jar
resteasy-jettison-provider-2.3.1.GA.jar
resteasy-spring-2.2.1.GA.jar
scannotation-1.0.3.jar
resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.10.Final.jar
jackson-annotaions-2.3.4.jar
jackson-databind-2.3.4.jar
```

Am I missing some thing here?

Comment: You need to add @RequestBody annotation before Test test in the method parameter.

Comment: You are mixing jars from jackson 1.6, 1.9, 2.2 and 2.3 and wonder why it doesn't work... Never mix jars of different versions of a framework.

Comment: @dhana1310 '@RequestBody' Paramater is not presented.

Comment: @M. Deinum - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs

For these Jars.Above 1.9.* is not available

Comment: Because you are looking at the wrong stuff. You already have `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`. Again you are mixing things you shouldn't be mixing. I strongly suggest looking at your other dependencies as well, as those seem to be using mixing different versions as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Response Body works fine for GET call. it seems jakson is able parse model class to json when constructing the response.
Are you suggesting to remove this jar ? jackson-jaxrs-json-provider. I dont have the privilege to get a maven dependency tree. I'm using ANT here. it's pretty pain full to identity which jar overlaps what

Comment: You are using Jackson 2.3, so which do you think you shold remove.

Comment: Also I would strongly suggest to start using Maven or Gradle, it will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I removed jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.2.1.jar. Still getting exactly the same exception. So it could be it might not the jar which made the overlap. 
I won't be a able to migrate to maven or gradle as of now. Yes if it was there dependency management would be much easy

Comment: Again you are mixnig jars from 4 different versions of jackson, why do you think removing a jar instead of fixing the version mismatches would work.